# Checking non-negative even integer in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to programming and currently learning Python. I would like to write a program that :

1. request user to input a non-negative even integer.
2. request the user to input again if not fulfil non-negative even integer.

```py
N = input("Please enter an non-negative even integer: ") #request user to input
```

And the criteria checking code is:

```py
N == int(N) #it is integer
N % 2 == 0 #it is even number
N >=0 # it is non-negative number
```

But how should I combine them?

Comment: `N == int(N) #it is integer` -> that doesn't work this way in Py3, remember? Try entering `'3' == 3` in Python and you'll see.

Comment: So i just need to add N % 2 == 0 next to if N > 0 in the previous post would be the best answer?

Comment: If you put an `and` in-between, yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. since the question is tagged *python-2.7*, use `raw_input` instead of `input` (which is used in python-3.x).
2. Use `str.isdigit` to check if a string is an positive integer, `int(N)` would raise `ValueError` if the input couldn't be converted into integer.
3. Use a `while loop` to request user input if condition not fulfilled, `break` when you get a valid input.

e.g.,

```
while True:
    N = raw_input("Please enter an non-negative even integer: ") #request user to input
    if N.isdigit(): # accepts a string of positive integer, filter out floats, negative ints
        N = int(N)
        if N % 2 == 0: #no need to test N>=0 here
            break
print 'Your input is: ', N
```

Comment: Change `input` to `raw_input`. The question is tagged Python 2.7 (though not by OP)

Comment: `N.isdigit()` being true means that you don't need to test for `N>=0`.

Comment: Oh well, the tag has changed to Python-3.x

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`and` operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/And_operator):

```
while True:
    s = input("Please enter an non-negative even integer: ")
    # Use raw_input instead of input in Python 2
    try:
        N = int(s)
    except ValueError:
        continue  # Not an integer, try again

    if N % 2 == 0 and N >= 0:
        break  # Abort the infinite loop
```

Comment: It should be noted that `N == int(N)` doesn't work here in Py3, because `N` is a string.

Comment: Updated with a Python 2.x and (with a small change) 3.x-compatible version.

Comment: Hi. Indeed i m using Python3.3.3. Why my question is unlike Python3?

Comment: @SteveJessop It was not obvious, but the OP mentionned that in [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21748910/296974).

Comment: @Yin: your question is unlike Python 3 because you used `N == int(N)`. As you've been told (on your previous question) that's wrong in Python 3. So people like me who hadn't seen your previous question will assume you're using Python 2 in which it does (more or less) work.

Answer (score 1):

Compared to other versions presented here, I prefer to loop without using the `break` keyboard. You can loop until the number entered is positive AND even, with an initial value set to `-1`:

```
n = -1
while n < 0 or n % 2 != 0:
    try:
        n = int(input("Please enter an non-negative even integer: ")) 
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter a integer value")


print("Ok, %s is even" % n)
```

Comment: The tag was erroneously added by someone else. Indeed, the OP uses Py3.

Comment: Ok, it's the occasion to won the "Cleanup" badge for rollback, hoorray!

Comment: shall use int(raw_input....) instead of int(input(...))... input equals eval(raw_input(...)), uncessary performance lost.

Comment: @ray_linn python3 tag, so no `raw_input` here.

Answer (score 0):

Just another solution:

```
>>> def non_neg(n):
...     try:
...         if n & 1 == 0 and n > 0:
...             return 'Even Positive Number'
...     except:
...         pass
...     return 'Wrong Number'
...
>>> for i in [-1,-2,2,3,4,0.5,'a']:
...     print i, non_neg(i)
...
-1 Wrong Number
-2 Wrong Number
2 Even Positive Number
3 Wrong Number
4 Even Positive Number
0.5 Wrong Number
a Wrong Number
>>>
```

Comment: DRY, Don't Repeat Yourself. Omit the first `return 'Wrong Number'` and replace the 2nd one with `pass`. Put `return 'Wrong Number'` at the end of the function.

Answer (score -2):

code for fun:

```
  result=[ x for x in [input("Please enter a number:")] if isinstance(x,int) and x>0 and x%2 ==0]
```

Excuting this list comprehension ,will get you an empty list if occurs any illegal key-in like 0.1, 'abc',999.

code for best practice:

There is quite popular to take all validation expression into lambda for python, for example, like django so :

```
isPositiveEvenNum=lambda x: x if isinstance(x,int) and x>0 and x%2 ==0 else None

while not isPositiveEvenNum(input("please enter a number:")):
    print "None Positive Even Number!"
```

this can also be writen as

```
isPositiveEvenNum=lambda x: (isinstance(x,int) and x>0 and x%2 ==0) or False

while not isPositiveEvenNum(input("please enter a number:")):
    print "None Positive Even Number!"
```

to solve the input and raw_input difference between 2.x and 3.x:

```
import sys
eval_input =lambda str: input(str) if sys.version_info<(3,0,0) else eval(input(str))
```

then just call eval_input

Comment: Thanks for your comment. i added() for print while it output "No Positive Even Number" even i input 6.

Comment: All problem are caused by 2.x to 3.x change. a). in 2.x , print supports "softspace", but 3.x does not . b) 3.x input function equal 2.x raw_input, so all you key in are string if under 3.x, this make isinstance(x,int) return false. using eval(input(...)) in 3.x can fix this issue.