# Can't figure out how to calculate user inputted integer to factorial

Tags: python, python-3.x, factorial

I started an introduction to Python course in september and I've barely been keeping up. This week the assignment has left me in a fritz. I have gotten help from my teacher and [tried my best to use my resources before its overdue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21748910/factorial-calculation-using-python) so I'm getting a little bit of an understanding but it just isn't clicking for me. I've made a lot of corrections over the week so my code is looking better than it was but I still don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Instead of creating a factorial for n it is just displaying n as the input value from the user. I have tried entering factorial(n) on various lines and it only gives me an EOF error. Could someone explain what I'm doing wrong? my belief is that i need to call the factorial function, but I can't seem to format it correctly.

```
def factorial(n):
    if n==0:
        return 1
    else:
        recurse = factorial(n-1)
        result = n * recurse
        return result




done=False
while not done:
    n=input('Enter a Positive Integer \n>>>')
    try:
        n=int(n)
        if n>=0:
            done=True
    except:
        print('try again')

print('n is ', n)
```

Comment: You say you "have tried entering factorial(n) on various lines" - can you give us an example of the one attempt you thought most likely to succeed? What result did that give you and what did you expect?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Function for Factorial in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136447/function-for-factorial-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Simple fix.

```
def factorial(n):
    if n==0:
        return 1
    else:
        recurse = factorial(n-1)
        result = n * recurse
        return result




done=False
while not done:
    n=input('Enter a Positive Integer \n>>>')
    try:
        n=int(n)
        if n>=0:
            done=True
    except:
        print('try again')

print('n is ', factorial(n))
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the factorial of n you need to call the function.
For example: res = factorial(n)

Comment: okay thank you. I simply wasnt applying the function in the print statement

I'm still extremely new to python. Newbie mistake

Comment: PLEASE don't store the results of the `factorial()` function call in a variable called `factorial`!